# How to select 6 months of data in MySQL, grouped between the 22nd and 21st of the next month

Tags: mysql

I have a table that contains the amount of data used each day, it looks something like this:

```
date       | bytes
------------------
2014-01-1  | 12345 
2014-01-2  | 56789
2014-01-3  | 78901
...
2014-02-1  | 12345
2014-02-2  | 56789
2014-02-3  | 78901
...
```

What I need to do is get the last 6 monthly totals, however the month must start on the 22nd day of the month and finish on the 21st day of the following month. For the current month it should start on the 22nd and finish today.

The best I can come up with is the following, the problem is - it is very messy and doesn't seem to give the correct result.

```
SELECT monthname(`date`),sum(`bytes`) 
FROM `trafficDaily` 
WHERE `date` between STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT(  "22,", MONTH( NOW( ) )-6 ,  ",", YEAR( NOW( ) ) ) ,  "%d,%m,%Y" ) 
and STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT(  "21,", MONTH( NOW( ) ) ,  ",", YEAR( NOW( ) ) ) ,  "%d,%m,%Y" ) 
group by month(DATE_SUB(`date`, INTERVAL 21 DAY)) 
order by `date`
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so by using user-defined variables to track the the change of month i.e in your case month starts from 21st

```
SELECT 
MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(group_day, '%m')) month_name ,
SUM(`bytes`) `sum` 
 FROM (
SELECT *,
 @changemonth:= CASE
    WHEN DAY(`date`) > 21 
    THEN @month
    WHEN MONTH(`date`) <> @month
    THEN @month
    ELSE @month - 1
  END  group_day,
@month:= MONTH(`date`)
FROM
  t ,(SELECT @changemonth:=0,
      @month:= (SELECT MONTH(`date`) FROM t
      WHERE `date` > NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH ORDER BY `date` LIMIT 1) aa
     ) tt
  WHERE `date` > NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH 
  ORDER BY `date`
    )  a 
GROUP BY group_day
```

### [Demo for last 3 months](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/57d5c/12)

**Edit from comments** for the case when January lies in last 6 month period

```
SELECT 
MONTHNAME(
  STR_TO_DATE(
    CASE WHEN group_day < 1 
    THEN 12 ELSE group_day                       
    END, '%m'
  )
) month_name ,
SUM(`bytes`) `sum` 
 FROM (
SELECT *,
 @changemonth:= CASE
    WHEN DAY(`date`) > 21 
    THEN @month
    WHEN MONTH(`date`) <> @month
    THEN @month
    ELSE @month - 1
  END  group_day,
@month:= MONTH(`date`)
FROM
  t ,(SELECT @changemonth:=0,
      @month:= (SELECT MONTH(`date`) FROM t
      WHERE `date` > NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH ORDER BY `date` LIMIT 1) aa
     ) tt
  WHERE `date` > NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH 
  ORDER BY `date`
    )  a 
GROUP BY group_day
```

### [Demo with January](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/046b0/6)

Comment: This query will fail when the date is in January. (Actually the month name will be NULL)

Comment: Your solution works and I appreciate the demo, I've subsequently discovered that my original function works and the problem was with the data. Whose solution do you think would be more efficient in terms of CPU load?

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two options:

**1st option**

Create a calendar table and assign the 'business month' to each days. You can prepare your table for a long time period, then you can join to that table by date and you can do the grouping. If you have to do this calculation regularry, this is a good solution. (You can upgrade and use the calendar table to do several tasks)

**2nd option**

You can calculate the 'business month' by the date using the following query. (Please note, that I did not tested this query, so there could be typos).

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN DAY(date) >= 22 THEN CONCAT(YEAR(date), '-', MONTH(date))
    ELSE CONCAT(YEAR(date - INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '-', MONTH(date - INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
  END AS m,
  SUM(bytes)
FROM
  log -- Use your table name instead :)
GROUP BY
  CASE
    WHEN DAY(date) >= 22 THEN CONCAT(YEAR(date), '-', MONTH(date))
    ELSE CONCAT(YEAR(date - INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '-', MONTH(date - INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
  END
```

You can adjust the calculation to your needs.